# C# Adding Filter to combobox dropdown list

Tags: c#, winforms, filter, combobox, dropdownbox

Need some help with adding filter to my `ComboBox` drop down list(windows Forms Visual studio 2015)

The drop down is populated as per below:

```
public ReconciliationReport()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += FindDLL;

    this.sRootDirectory = Properties.Resources.sRootDirectory;

    string[] arrProjectList = Directory.GetDirectories(sRootDirectory).Select(Directory => Path.GetFileName(Directory)).ToArray();
    Array.Sort(arrProjectList);

    int iProjectCount = arrProjectList.Length;
    this.DropDownListSize = iProjectCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < iProjectCount; i++)
    {
        SelectJobDropdown.Items.Add(arrProjectList[i]);
    }
}
```

This gives me a nice drop down list of all current directories. 
[image]

Now, I need to add a filer to show only items which contain a text typed into the `ComboBox`itself regardless if the dropdown list itself is open or not.

I have disabled both `AutoCompleteMode` and `AutoCompleteSource` as it was not working as expected with the opened droped down list. It was opening additonal list on top the existing one but I could only select from the dropdown under it. See print screen below:
[image]

The list on top is inactive and I cannot select the text but also does not give an option to display substrings.

Only have one even for the box itself which is

```
private void SelectJobDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //Plenty of code here 
}
```

Can someone point in the right direction how to filter the list as I type within the box itself.

Please  NOTE I have been using C# for only 3 weeks so might get confused with some of the terminology or other aspects of this language etc.

Comment: Not even a single comment or answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WinForms ComboBox DropDown and Autocomplete window both appear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064780/winforms-combobox-dropdown-and-autocomplete-window-both-appear)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I have different requirements sadly. I do not want to display a new list as  I  type along. I want to filter the main list as type. This solution must search for any text within combobox item and not just the starting characters. The solution you have suggested does include additional list and does not allow for searching any string within an item. So for example if item contains 99999 Hello World, I want to be able to display matching line by typing any of the words in the item and not just 99999. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I'm starting to think I will need to add a new event(textChanged or TextAppend) and and search the array for any matches and rebuild the list each time but not too sure if this is the best solution. Cheers

Comment: I would not rebuild the list each time. I would extract the values based on the filter and bind it to the list. I am working right now on a solution, but have not yet figured it out. My problem is to write into the `ComboBox`.

Comment: ok I got a preliminary solution for your problem. But it is using an extra `TextBox` for the filter entry. It should be possible to write the filter directly into the `ComboBox`, I just need time to figure it out. When I do, I edit my answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suggest to use 2 Lists. 1 for the original values

```
List<string> arrProjectList;

public ReconciliationReport()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += FindDLL;

    this.sRootDirectory = Properties.Resources.sRootDirectory;

    arrProjectList = Directory.GetDirectories(sRootDirectory).Select(Directory => Path.GetFileName(Directory)).ToList();
    arrProjectList.Sort();

    // then just bind it to the DataSource of the ComboBox
    SelectJobDropdown.DataSource = arrProjectList;
    // don't select automatically the first item
    SelectJobDropdown.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

and 1 for the filtered values. In this example I use a `TextBox` to catch the filter text. In the `TextChanged` event take the filter text and pull out only those values from the original `arrProjectList` List. You would need an extra option at the end to reset the binding to the old list if the filter is empty.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filter_param = textBox1.Text;

    List<string> filteredItems = arrProjectList.FindAll(x => x.Contains(filter_param));
    // another variant for filtering using StartsWith:
    // List<string> filteredItems = arrProjectList.FindAll(x => x.StartsWith(filter_param));

    comboBox1.DataSource = filteredItems;

    // if all values removed, bind the original full list again
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = arrProjectList;
    }

    // this line will make sure, that the ComboBox opens itself to show the filtered results       
}
```

**EDIT**

I found a Solution for typing the filter into the `ComboBox` directly. The filtering is the same procedure, but using the `TextUpdate` event it is necessary to unselect the `SelectedIndex` which is automatically set to the first element after the binding. Then I guess you want to proceed to write your filter (more than just one letter), write the filter back into the `ComboBox.Text` property and set the cursor position to the end:

```
private void comboBox1_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filter_param = comboBox1.Text;

    List<string> filteredItems = arrProjectList.FindAll(x => x.Contains(filter_param));
    // another variant for filtering using StartsWith:
    // List<string> filteredItems = arrProjectList.FindAll(x => x.StartsWith(filter_param));

    comboBox1.DataSource = filteredItems;

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter_param))
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = arrProjectList;
    }
    comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;

    // this will ensure that the drop down is as long as the list
    comboBox1.IntegralHeight = true;

    // remove automatically selected first item
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

    comboBox1.Text = filter_param;

    // set the position of the cursor
    comboBox1.SelectionStart = filter_param.Length;
    comboBox1.SelectionLength = 0;            
}
```

Et voilà automatic filtering with a nice display and arrow selection afterwards.

**EDIT 2**

for case insensitive search you can use this:

```
List<string> filteredItems = arrProjectList.FindAll(x => x.ToLower().Contains(filter_param.ToLower()));
```

NOTE:

After the opening of the dropdownlist the [cursor will disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093067/why-combobox-hides-cursor-when-droppeddown-is-set). To prevent this the `Cursor.Current` has to be set to `Cursor.Defualt`

```
comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
```

Comment: Cool Thanks. I will give that a go and report back.

Comment: Great. Just reading through it. Cheers Will let you know later.

Comment: I had to add electJobDropdown.SelectedIndex = -1; to the intial part as it was populating list with the very first value rather then leaving it blank. As a result it fails in the next method - see this http://pastebin.com/L8pkB0PG

Comment: Understand why it fails but is there a way to prevent a change of index so this code is actual only executed when I select item from the list?

Comment: I have changed SelectJobDropdown_SelectionChangeCommitted nd it works almost. I does not work with numbers. When I type 3 only displays the very first match rather then all matches. Works fine for a text but need to add case insensitivity. Any idea about the digits issues? Cheers

Comment: It also seems that it does the same if I start searching for 2 first characters. It seems to work from the 3rd. Also noticed that if I deleted appended text it opens another list with matching records starting with the typed character.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry had autoCompleteMode enabled to append lol. Work like a treat now cheers very much...

Comment: My courser seems to disappear when I start typing without opening the drop down list. Is there a way of enabling that? It works fine with the drop down list opened.

Comment: "electJobDropdown.SelectedIndex = -1; to the intial part " I have it also in my code I forgot to paste it in. Sorry for that.

Comment: No worries. How to fix that missing cursor? it vanishes and I cannot even click any buttons on my form :(

Comment: @TomPisz "I does not work with numbers." It works in my case. Did you fix that with shutting off the autoCompleteMode? The missing cursor problem disappears as soon as you have selected an item from the ComboBox with the arrow keys and enter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129893/discussion-between-mong-zhu-and-tom-pisz).

Comment: Sorry for posting another comment but have a bug and cant find a way around it. Basically, when text is selected and dropped down list opened and text is deleted the size of the drop down remains minimal. I have tried resetting the height but still the same. See http://prnt.sc/dg0pzl. It also seems that as soon I start typing the size of dro down reduces. Please help.

Comment: @TomPisz I would need to see the code for this. It does not happen in my code. The size should reduce when you start typing, because you limit the choice with your search pattern. But it should definitely jump to the original list when the entire text is deleted. I have the chat open, you can write there

Comment: I have discovered an issue with comboBox1.IntegralHeight = true; When enabled, it makes the drop down window as long as the list that feeds into it rather then still to original defined size. Any idea. Moved some of the code onto separate project and therefore can post everything related.

Comment: @TomPisz a simple trick should do it: reset the `IntegralHeight` property and put it in front of the `DroppedDown = true` line:   `comboBox1.IntegralHeight = false;
            comboBox1.IntegralHeight = true;
            comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;`

Comment: @TomPisz If I misunderstood you, then post a new question and we`ll have a look into the code

Comment: amazing! this is pretty relevant and the closest match to an answer I found yet! Good work!

Comment: @sksallaj thank you, I am glad to hear that it helped you. You could also upvote the question since it also led you to this answer ;)

Comment: That was the first thing I did, I'm a good stackoverflow user :-D

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using a Dictionary as data source, the following can be useful.
I created a static function in the form to be able to reuse it as I have several ComboBox instances for which I wanted to have the same behavior.
Simply call the function from the TextUpdate event passing the control name and the source dictionary.

```
private static void FilterComboBox(ComboBox combo, Dictionary<int, string> dataSource)
{
  var filter = combo.Text;
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
    return;

  var filteredItems = dataSource.Where(kv => kv.Value.Contains(filter)).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value);

  combo.DisplayMember = "Value";
  combo.ValueMember = "Key";
  combo.DataSource = new BindingSource(filteredItems, null);

  // this will ensure that the drop down is as long as the list
  combo.IntegralHeight = false;
  combo.IntegralHeight = true;

  combo.DroppedDown = true;
  
  // remove automatically selected first item
  combo.SelectedIndex = -1;
  combo.Text = filter;

  // set the position of the cursor
  combo.SelectionStart = filter.Length;
  combo.SelectionLength = 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i added keyPress event and its working ok for me. it's just closing the original dropDown list.

```
private void combobox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    combobox.DroppedDown = false;
}
```