# combobox dropdown out of range exception

Tags: c#, winforms, filter, combobox, dropdownbox

I tried to bulid a filter for combobox when typing text in to it and it displays dropdown with matching values from combo list
I used guide from here: [C# Adding Filter to combobox dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40984605/c-sharp-adding-filter-to-combobox-dropdown-list)
But I've noticed when I'm typing characters that has no matching values from combo list and then press Enter or click on the mouse it throws an Exception type of
`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` and says InvalidArgument=Value
this is my code:

```
private void comboBox1_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                string filter_param = comboBox1.Text;

                string[] filteredItems = Array.FindAll(arrProjectList, c => c.Contains(filter_param));  //'arrProjectList' is a global string array that holds and fills the combobox values
                // another variant for filtering using StartsWith:
                //List<string> filteredItems = arrProjectList.FindAll(x => x.StartsWith(filter_param));

                comboBox1.DataSource = filteredItems;

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter_param))
                {
                    comboBox1.DataSource = filteredItems;
                }
                comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;

                // this will ensure that the drop down is as long as the list
                comboBox1.IntegralHeight = true;

                // remove automatically selected first item
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

                comboBox1.Text = filter_param;

                // set the position of the cursor
                comboBox1.SelectionStart = filter_param.Length;
                comboBox1.SelectionLength = 0;

                //comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
                //comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error");
            }
        }
```

I didn't find solution for that in the guide. How it can be fixed?

Comment: Have you stepped through in debug mode?  On which line is the error thrown?  My initial guess is that your problem has to do with the fact that if the input does not match anything in the list, then ´Array.FindAll´ will not find anything, so you are setting the DataSource to an invalid object.  You may need to test filteredItems.Count for positive value before assigning it as DataSource

Comment: I added a condition for: `comboBox1.DataSource = filteredItems;` so it will only performed if: `if(filteredItems.Length > 0)` and now it seems to work fine