# How to fix displayMember?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm working on a application and needs to search the combobox with Contains instead of StartsWith, can't bind displaymember.

Tried to bind it directlu to the class but no luck.

```
    private void customersDropDown_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var company = (NMA0701R)companyDropDown.SelectedItem;
        var items = priceCalculatorContext.GetCustomers(company.CompanyNumber, 0);
        List<string> stringList = items.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();

        string filter_param = customersDropDown.Text;
        List<string> filteredItems = stringList.FindAll(x => x.ToLower().Contains(filter_param.ToLower()));

        customersDropDown.DisplayMember = "FullCustomer";
        customersDropDown.ValueMember = "CustomerNumber";
        customersDropDown.DataSource = filteredItems;

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter_param))
        {
            customersDropDown.DataSource = items;
        }
        customersDropDown.DroppedDown = true;
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

        // this will ensure that the drop down is as long as the list
        customersDropDown.IntegralHeight = true;

        // remove automatically selected first item
        customersDropDown.SelectedIndex = -1;

        customersDropDown.Text = filter_param;

        // set the position of the cursor
        customersDropDown.SelectionStart = filter_param.Length;
        customersDropDown.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
```

I have used this answer to try get my code working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40990757/11707295 
I want to be able to do a Contains search instead of StartsWith.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DisplayMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_ListControl_DisplayMember) and [ValueMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_ListControl_ValueMember) property of a combobox expect the string name of the property that you are binding to in your datasource.

So in your example, setting the DisplayMember to "FullCustomer" and ValueMember to "CustomerNumber" means that you expect your datasource to be a list of Customer objects. But you're setting your datasource to a List of string objects.

In addition, this line:

```
List<string> stringList = items.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();
```

is attempting to convert the customer objects to string which is incorrect.

You can use the items variable directly:

```
        var items = priceCalculatorContext.GetCustomers(company.CompanyNumber, 0);
        string filter_param = comboBox1.Text.ToLower();
        var filteredList = items.ToList().FindAll(x => x.FullCustomer.ToLower().Contains(filter_param));

        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "FullCustomer";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "CustomerNumber";


        if (filteredList.Count() > 0)
            comboBox1.DataSource = filteredList;

        //set the datasource to items if the filter is empty, or the filtered list is empty
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter_param) || filteredList.Count() == 0)
        {
            comboBox1.DataSource = items;
        }
```