# Why does the cursor disappear on combobox DroppedDown in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox whose ***DroppedDownStyle=DropDownList*** and on its **GotFocus** event i have written the following code so that as soon as the comboBox receives the focus it opens it's list

```
static void comboBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
    }
```

Now as soon as the above code executes **my cursor disappears**. I know the workaround of it is

```
static void comboBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;//This statement
    }
```

### Question

I want to know the REASON (not the solution) behind the disappearing of the cursor on combobox's Dropped down.

Comment: probably a winforms / win32api bug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why ComboBox hides cursor when DroppedDown is set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093067/why-combobox-hides-cursor-when-droppeddown-is-set) Edit: In the other thread, there's a link to the bug report, but it's broken now

Comment: @OriNachum man please try to read the complete question. I already have the solution and i am asking the reason for it.

Comment: @Agent_Spock, I read, and as I wrote: they specifically mention this as a bug and refer to the bug report in MS's site- unless you want to understand why the *bug* is occurring, in which case, you can revise your question. Keep in mind, though, that answering this probably requires understanding the programming and quirks behind combobox.

Comment: @OriNachum earlier i visited the site you were talking about and it redirects to a no longer existing Microsoft bug link that is why i was asking if you have any more theory or knowledge on this question?

Comment: @Agent_Spock, it works like that because of the code: either intentional (Feature) or not (A bug). In case of the later - just open a bug report and see what they say. I found other mentions of it, but people just found a solution and went on, so it won't be far-fetched to conclude it was not prioritized and deleted. But the *discussion* about it was already laid in that thread. Part of your answer should have mentioned it as part of your research, and added it still occurs and the bug report link broken.